# Implementing a Custom Membership Provider with slightly bizarre requirements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, mobile-website

Building a new Mobile Web Platform for Mobile Users to purchase & download content on their handsets. In the past we've used a completely bespoke login mechanism but I'm investigating using a Custom Membership Provider for the next version of the Platform.

The thing is, we have some slightly odd "login" mechanism requirements, so I'm not 100% sure that a MembershipProvider is the best fit.

Just looking for some general feed back on the requirements below with a "Yes, Membership Provider is a good fit" or "No, you're banging a square peg in a round hole"

Requirements

1. User may be required to login with a "Mobile Number" (username) & "Pin" (password)
   This fits pretty well, as they've already signed up and confirmed with an SMS and it satisfies the `ValidateUser(string username, string password)` Method Implementation
2. User may be required to login with only a "Mobile Number". In this case, we don't bother doing the identity verification on our side. It reduces the number of steps for the user and verification is done by the particular operator when we attempt to bill them. (The operators can validate that the mobile number entered, matches with the handset when it hits the operator payment site)... so even though users have a password, we'd need to bluff the membership provider in someway, and let them in with a blank password.
3. User doesn't need to login at all. In this case, we can transparently bounce the user to a special network operator webpage, and we'll get the Mobile Number in Headers when they're transparently bounced back to us. In this case, we'd need to programmatically take that number from the headers, perform the login on their behalf in the code behind (again without any pin/password) and the user would be magically auto logged in.

Requirement 2 & 3 are bit odd. We essentially have 3 different login mechanisms that the one membership provider would need to satisfy.

- User Entered Mobile & User Entered Pin
- User Entered Mobile Only (code behind I suppose to satisfy the pin requirement)
- Completely Transparent Login (code behind to do the entire login process)

Anyone got any comments/feed back on the above or have any advice on any bizarre membership provider implementation you've done in the past.

Comment: i have almost similar problem as to yours.. if you can suggest me want to do.=> Q:I am developing custom membership provider,I allow a user to login via his emailID as username but MembershipProvider.ValidateUser() takes User name as argument (and my user have username too, just to show in their profile). so what should i do. Currently i have implemented the ValidateUser() to take emailid in that argument.. but it dosen't looks like good practise.. so waht to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could work.  We do #3 on one of our sites.  Here is a chunk of code that we use to take care of it.  To use this, create a login page (transparentlogin.aspx or something similar), make sure that the web.config file allows anonymous access to this page, and put code like this in the page_load function for the transparentlogin.aspx page:

```
const string specialpassword = "ThisIsOurSpecialPasswordForBehindTheScenesLogin";

if (MobileNumberFoundInHeader())
{
  string username = GetMobileNumberFromHeaders();
  // Authenticate the user behind the scenes
  System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
  System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, specialpassword);
}
else
{
  throw new Exception ("Mobile Number Missing");
}
```

Then, in the ValidateUser function in the MembershipProvider, make sure you do a check like this:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
 const string specialpassword = "ThisIsOurSpecialPasswordForBehindTheScenesLogin";

 bool ValidationSuccess = false;

 // If the password being passed in is the right secret key (same  
 // for all users), then we will say that the password matches the
 // username, thus allowing the user to login 
 if (password == specialpassword)
 {
   ValidationSuccess = true;
 }

 if (DoStandardUsernamePasswordVerification() == true)
 {
   ValidationSuccess = true;
 }

 return ValidationSuccess;
}
```

As for requirement #2, I'm a little confused.  What exactly is an operator?  I thought we were dealing with a mobile phone using a web browser to browse to a website.  Where does the operator fit into that?  If the solution I propose above doesn't help, please post a response with more details about the Operator.

Tim

Comment: cheers... yeah that's pretty much the conclusion I came to. Re: "Operators"... I mean the Mobile Phone Network Operators... e.g. AT&T, Vodafone, T-Mobile etc...